# flopy The program mf6 does not exist or is not executable

Tags: flopy

**when I execute sim.run_simulation()  error is showing "The program mf6 does not exist or is not executable".**

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the model executable to a valid executable path. If your model is a MODFLOW 6 model, then you should set your executable path to the MODFLOW 6 executable.

Example:

```
import flopy
mf = flopy.modflow.Modflow.load('model.nam', exe_nam='my-modflow6-executable')
```

Replace `my-modflow6-executable` with the full file path (including the file name and extension) to the appropriate executable.

You can see the attribute [here](https://flopy.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.2/source/flopy.mf6.mfmodel.html#flopy.mf6.mfmodel.MFModel.exe_name).